# Straightedge Only Construction of Tangents to Circle

Tags: circles, geometric-construction

Currently, there exists a question regarding straightedge only constructions; however, my specific question pertains something that is not found in that thread, and I do not think it will be answered any time soon for that matter.

Foreplay aside, my question centers around the following simple fact:

*Given a circle $\Gamma$ and a point $P$ outside of $\Gamma$, it is possible to construct the two tangent lines from $P$ to the circle by straightedge alone, using the straightedge only construction of the polar line.*

My question is - where can I find a proof (or perhaps, could I be supplied with one) that this construction works?

Thanks in advance for any assistance. This is not homework, just mere curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Look at: http://mathafou.free.fr/themes_en/pole.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will give that a read! I was wondering if there was a textual reference (i.e. print source) of the proof as well - the typesetting and presentation on that site is not the cleanest to say the least.